# How to implement rotation of multiple images around an off-centre point in p5.js

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, game-physics, p5.js

I'm making a tower defense game using JavaScript and p5.js library. I have 2 images a *base* and a *gun*. The gun is drawn on top of the base to make it appear as a single unit. I need my gun to point towards the enemy(which follows a path). I need help to make the gun rotate on a point(not centre), keeping in mind that there can be several of these towers. I have tried translating(to change centre) and rotating but this doesn't work for many objects and obviously can't keep track of many objects.

I haven't seen any other question regarding this matter either, is there a better solution/alternative to what I'm trying to accomplish?

---

### Required Code

---

**Some Important Variables**

```
var isFireTowerPressed = false;    // checks if tower is placed
var FireTowerPos = [];    // location of every tower => [] - 2d array
```

**Preloaded Stuff**

```
function preload() {
    backgroundImg = loadImage("http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/extra/map1.png");
    [...]
    firetowerbaseImg = loadImage("http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/towers/firetowerbase.png");
    firetowerturretImg = loadImage("http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/towers/firetowergun.png");

}
```

**Draw Every Frame**

```
function draw() 
{

    background(60, 238, 161);
    [...]
    if (isFireTowerPressed == true)    //checks if I have pressed the button to place the tower
    {
        image(firetowerbaseImg, mouseX - 28, mouseY - 28);
        // show range circle
        noFill();
        stroke(0,0,0);
        strokeWeight(1);
        circle(mouseX, mouseY, 300);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < FireTowerPos.length; i++) 
    {
        image(firetowerbaseImg, FireTowerPos[i][0], FireTowerPos[i][1]);
        image(firetowerturretImg, FireTowerPos[i][0], FireTowerPos[i][1]-20);

    }

}
```

**Mouse Click Event**

```
function mouseClicked()
{

    if (isFireTowerPressed==true && mouseX+28 <= 750) // place-able area
    {
        FireTowerPos.push([mouseX-28, mouseY-28]);
        isFireTowerPressed = false;
    }
}
```

---

**The picture shows the 2 pictures I'm using(base & gun). I need to be able to rotate the gun towards the enemy**

[image: Picture to help visualize problem]

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translating and rotating works for several objects if you also use the [push()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and [pop()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop) methods, from the p5 library, which allow you to *store* the current settings.

To rotate towards a given point the function [`atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1`)](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/atan2) is the commonly used method.

To illustrate, I wrote this quick snippet in which the guns will rotate towards the mouse only if the mouse is within range of the gun.

```js
let gunSprite

function preload(){
  gunSprite = loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/ayvg9J2.jpg", ()=>{
    gunSprite.resize(20, 40)
  })
}

let guns = [
  { x: 160, y: 80,  angle: 0, range: 100 },
  { x: 300, y: 200, angle: 0, range: 150 },
  { x: 100, y: 240, angle: 0, range: 120 }
]

function setup(){
  createCanvas(600, 400)
  noFill()
}

function draw(){
  background(200)
  for(let gun of guns)
      drawGun(gun)
}

function drawGun(gun){
  
  const isWithinRange = dist(mouseX, mouseY, gun.x, gun.y) < gun.range
  if(isWithinRange)
    gun.angle = atan2(mouseY - gun.y, mouseX - gun.x) + radians(90)
  
  push()
    translate(gun.x, gun.y)
    rect(-25, -20, 50, 40) // Draw the gun base
    ellipse(0, 0, gun.range*2) // display the gun range
    rotate(gun.angle)
    image(gunSprite, -10, -40) // Set the offset of the gun sprite and draw the gun
  pop()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is being ```pushed``` and ```popped``` ? I'm still new to JavaScript and I've only seen ```push``` and ```pop``` being used as ```array.push();```

Comment: In this context `push` and `pop` are p5 methods that allow you to "... change the style and transformation settings and later return to what you had." Basically you create a _save point_ of your current transformations and drawing settings (translations, rotations, colors, styles, etc.) with push, change them according to your needs, and then return to the _save point_ with pop.